# Ckeditor delete some elements

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

In ckeditor editor and **(ADDED) using Drupal 7**

I click Html Source and paste:

```
<span><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></span>
```

then ckeditor remove the `a` and the `i` elements to become:

```
<span></span>
```

The problem is that I can't put a `i` element inside an `a` element:

```
 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

How can I solve this?

I had a similar problem with the `span` element which I solved adding in the **Custom JavaScript configuration**:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

`allowedContent` means ONLY allow these entities. `extraAllowedContent` means allow these entities in addition to default ones. So you can use one of these:

```
        CKEDITOR.replace('textarea_id', {
            allowedContent: 'span i a'
        });
```

Or

```
        CKEDITOR.replace('textarea_id', {
            extraAllowedContent: 'i a'
        });
```

Comment: replace method is used to make textarea or div a ckeditor instance. Didn't you use this method? I haven't use drupal at all maybe it does in automatically way. More information [link](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace)